# android on new activity start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want my activity the recognize when it is left and a new activity is started so for example when i'll do

```
startActivity(intent);
```

It will perform a certain code.
I tried using onPause();
But it only work on leaving the activity manually

Comment: What method are you using? I assume it's `startActivity(intent)`, since `startnewactivity(intent)` isn't a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Why don't you perform the operation before calling the new `startActivity()` and go read about the android activity life cycle to understand how it works

EDIT::

if i truly understand what you are saying..then i think you are looking for `onStop()` method

Comment: because i an calling the startactivity about 60 times in my code

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Android activity lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). `onPause` is called when "another activity comes to the foreground". If I understand your question correctly, it seems like overriding your first activity's `onPause` method will work. It's called when you add a new activity on the back stack or when you send the app to the background.

For convenience, here's the chart from the link I provided that I refer to for activity lifecycle questions:

[image]

Comment: I am doing that but for some reason when trying to run this code
 Intent goHome = new Intent();
            goHome.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            goHome.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
            startActivity(goHome);

The onePause does not come into action

Comment: Hm, I haven't used intents like that. I suggest you model your intents after this example: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#StartActivity